# Local code search

Tags: osx, self-hosted, search, macos

I have lots of personal projects sitting around from over the years that I want to be able to search. Sometimes there is a package or a function that I want to re-use.

I want this to run locally as a macOS service.

Something similar to Sourcegraph that runs locally on macOS would be nice.

I could keep all projects in one directory and then open VSCode, but I think that might use too many resources...

Comment: If just searching, have you tried grep or standard file search tools? Or do you also need the results to appear in a kind of IDE with highlighting and clicking to open referenced functions/etc?

Answer (score 0):

If speed is not of the essence, then [EasyFind](https://www.devontechnologies.com/apps/freeware) (freeware) is pretty comprehensive.
[It used to also be on the App Store, but seems to have gone now. The dev's site still lists it.]

It's only slow because it doesn't use an index, it runs right across your selected location top to bottom every time.

> Spotlight is great, but sometimes you need something more specialized. EasyFind finds files and folders by name, content, tags, or comments using advanced Boolean operators similar to DEVONthink and DEVONagent, wildcards, phrases, even regular expressions. It does not require indexing, is fast, and uses very little memory.